# Command to have lava increase creating a flood

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a command available to bedrock edtion that creates a lava flood? I want it where every 30 seconds the lava increase 1 block in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no single command to make this happen, you could use: `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 lava keep`. This works the same as a normal fill command, but doesn't destroy any blocks in its path.

If at the end of the game you wanted to get rid of the lava, you could use: `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 air replace lava`. This command replaces every lava block in the selected area with air, thus removing the lava from the area.

If you want more information on the fill command, go [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill)